# React add a variable name attribute

Tags: javascript, reactjs, attr

What is the cleanest way in React to add a variable name attribute?
The end result I want is: `<div data-flag>Hello</div>` where the name `data-flag` is stored in a `const` variable.

---

The ways I found now are:

```js
const DATA_FLAG = 'data-flag';

const Hello = ({ name }) => {
    const dataAttrs = { [DATA_FLAG]: true }
    return <div {...dataAttrs}>Hello {name}</div>;
}
```

Or this one-line version (but I find it less readable):

```js
const Hello = ({ name }) => <div {...{ [DATA_FLAG]: true }}>Hello {name}</div>;
```

You can play with it in [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mpqb87vy/)

---

These versions work fine if the attribute was variable (true or false) but in my case it's always `true` so I find it a bit over-killed and the syntax complex.

I would love to know if there is a cleaner way to achieve it.

I know that the best approach is to apply it directly like: `<div data-flag>Hello</div>` but I really need to store `data-flag` in a constant (as shared by other components).

Comment: object spread syntax seems like a completely fine solution. Why dont you put `const dataAttrs = { [DATA_FLAG]: '' }` in your shared utility file, and then just extend it on the components you want to? Before React [supported the object spread es6 syntax for attributes](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1683) you had to do `React.DOM.div(` syntax to get dynamic attributes.

Comment: I think this is your best bet for that right now : `<div {...dataAttrs}>`

Answer (score 1):

You could create a React element without using the JSX syntax. Something like this should work:

```
const DATA_FLAG = 'data-flag'

const Hello = ({ name }) => {
    const dataAttrs = { [DATA_FLAG]: true }
  return React.createElement('div', dataAttrs, `Hello ${name}`)
}
```

This only really makes the way you're passing in the attributes look easier on the eyes though. Don't think you'll get around defining a `dataAttrs` object for your props.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this alternative. But yeah seems like I need to keep the `dataAttrs` no matter what.